# filebeat configuration using elasticsearch

Tags: filebeat

I am Facing issue with Filebeat,i taken filebeat image docker pull docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.3.1
my filebeat.yml file is

```
filebeat.config:
  prospectors:
    path: ${path.config}/prospectors.d/*.yml
    reload.enabled: false
  modules:
    path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
    reload.enabled: false
processors:
- add_cloud_metadata:
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ['192.0.0.0:9200']
  username: elastic
  password: changeme
setup.kibana:
  host: '192.0.0.0:5601'
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/*.log
```

When i run filebeat i am getting yum.logs and harvester started for yum.log,Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The i guess the name of your log file is yum.log so what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: I take the path var/log/*.log path in filebeat in that so many files logs are there but filebeat displays only yum.logs that file is not there in path /var/log/*.log

Comment: remove `.log` and try. Also your previous comment says a different path than the file that you posted in question. so change it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Raghuveer,I mentioned path /var/log/* and another path /usr/loc/aaa/* ,But I am getting Output                                                  
 Harvester started for file: /var/log/tallylog
 Harvester started for file: /var/log/yum.log but in my system in that path yum.log is not there and tallylog is not there

Comment: I have log path in 1 location like /usr/loc/logs/abc/*/* ,i want to collect all logs to kibana using filebeat,Pls suggest to do that,Thanks in Advance